# iOS GoogleVR - 360 degree video playback issue

Tags: ios, swift, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

My app has 360-degree video playback and I am using GoogleVR's GVRRendererView class for it. I am trying to play a high-quality 360-degree video from the server. But the problem is that video streaming is very slow and I get below mentioned error message in the XCode console.

```
<AppName> [Symptoms] {
                     "transportType" : "HTTP Progressive Download",
                     "mediaType" : "HTTP Progressive Download",
                     "BundleID" : "AppID",
                     "name" : "MEDIA_PLAYBACK_STALL",
                     "interfaceType" : "WiredEthernet"
               }
```

How to resolve it?